# flutter: How to correctly use async and await to freeze and wait for certain function finish before executing next line of code

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

I am reading the `async-await` document and trying to use it to make a function wait for a return. According to my understanding(I am new to async), the `async` function executes line by line before the first `await` keyword, but I can't do so in the following code. How can I make this work?

```
  List<Map> testinglist = [];
//function that obtain data somwhere and where I want to work on
  Future<void> _getEventData() async {
    testinglist.clear();
    debugPrint('right after clear');
    print(testinglist.length);
//await here to get the return from database
    var snapshot2 = await fireBaseDB.child('event').once();
    Map map2 = snapshot2.value;
//Problem here: I used await here, so I supposed line after this execute only after this is finished?
    await map2.keys.toList().forEach((element) {
      fireBaseDB
          .child('event')
          .child(element)
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot innersnapshot) {
        testinglist.add(innersnapshot.value);
        debugPrint('after entering');
        print(testinglist.length);
      });
    });
    debugPrint('end entering');
    print(testinglist.length);
    debugPrint('end');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("print data"),
                onPressed: () {
                  debugPrint('before entering');
                  print(testinglist.length);
                  _getEventData();
                },
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("check length"),
                onPressed: _checkingLength,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
  ...
  }

The output isn't as I expected:
I/flutter (11527): before entering
I/flutter (11527): 3
I/flutter (11527): right after clear
I/flutter (11527): 0
I/flutter (11527): end entering
I/flutter (11527): 0
I/flutter (11527): end
I/flutter (11527): after entering
I/flutter (11527): 1
I/flutter (11527): after entering
I/flutter (11527): 2
I/flutter (11527): after entering
I/flutter (11527): 3
```

Why doesn't `after entering` come before `end entering`? Did I understand async and await wrongly? And How can I fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal in two ways:

1. By using `Future.forEach` and await for `innersnapshot` - like below:

```
await Future.forEach(map2.keys.toList(), (element) async {
  final innersnapshot = await fireBaseDB
    .child('event')
    .child(element)
    .once();
  testinglist.add(innersnapshot.value);
  debugPrint('after entering');
  print(testinglist.length);
});
```

2. By changing `foreach` loop to `for` loop, because `foreach` isn't the best choice to asynchronous function (less readable for others). Inside `for` loop use await for `innersnapshot` as well.

So change:

```
    await map2.keys.toList().forEach((element) {
      fireBaseDB
          .child('event')
          .child(element)
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot innersnapshot) {
        testinglist.add(innersnapshot.value);
        debugPrint('after entering');
        print(testinglist.length);
      });
    });
```

to:

```
for (var element in map2.keys.toList()) {
  final innersnapshot = await fireBaseDB
    .child('event')
    .child(element)
    .once();
  testinglist.add(innersnapshot.value);
  debugPrint('after entering');
  print(testinglist.length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for ur help, the second one works, but not the first one, it executes in the wrong order still(same output as my code). I will try it on more to see what the problem is.